# System.Data.SqlClient. Cannot use after install

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have problem about using the System.Data.SqlClient. I install it from nugget search but then when i got to my project it looks like i cant even use it.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace dvadvanced
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var buffer = new SqlConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

I add it but using System.Data.SqlClient just stays grey like i dont have it.

Comment: perhaps cos your code has "SqlClitent" not SqlClient ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake but it stays grey like even with Client*

Comment: What happens when you debug ? Is your program buildable ?

Comment: Make sure that your program or library has a Reference to the assembly `System.Data`. That assembly is what contains and provides the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. See **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx**

Comment: When i start debugging it goes well, but when i stop SqlConnection() is still underlined and still says: "The type or namespace name "SqlConnection" could not be found"

Comment: You never start debugging because according to the error message you are reporting the program does not build.  You are missing a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Data` before using the assembly `System.Data.SqlClient`.